# how does Piwik track link click events?

Tags: javascript, matomo

I personally do not use Piwik. I have developed a JavaScript tool/library for creating a menu system in SharePoint and someone who uses my library was asking about incorporating Piwik.

From what I have read I can see that Piwik catches/tracks `click` events. I suspect it does that by default for `<a>` tags that have a `href` attribute.

My JS library creates `<div>` elements with an `onclick` event. I've read and understand that I can manually fire a click event using Piwik's `trackLink` function function. I wanted to avoid doing that for numerous reasons.

So I wanted to see how exactly Piwik tracks click events so I can figure out how I can incorporate it in a more general way. I thought maybe I could make my `onclick` event fake something by creating an `<a>` element and executing it's `click` event but wasn't sure if that would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Piwik's [JS tracker source code](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/js/piwik.js).

For example:

- [`enableLinkTracking()`](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/js/piwik.js#L4930)

  > The default behaviour is to use actual click events. However, some browsers (e.g., Firefox, Opera, and Konqueror) don't generate click events for the middle mouse button.
  >
  > To capture more "clicks", the pseudo click-handler uses mousedown + mouseup events. This is not industry standard and is vulnerable to false positives (e.g., drag events).
- [`addClickListener()`](https://github.com/piwik/piwik/blob/master/js/piwik.js#L4037)

  ```
      function addClickListener(element, enable) {
          addEventListener(element, 'click', clickHandler(enable), false);

          if (enable) {
              addEventListener(element, 'mouseup', clickHandler(enable), false);
              addEventListener(element, 'mousedown', clickHandler(enable), false);
              addEventListener(element, 'contextmenu', clickHandler(enable), false);
          }
      }
  ```

Comment: The thing is I think `enableLinkTracking()` only works on links that existed when Piwik is loaded. How do I get it to track links that were created dynamically after Piwik is loaded? I tried `_paq(['trackEvent', url, 'link']);` but that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

IMTheNachoMan, you were very close to the solution.
Matomo (Piwik) have the Javascript `trackEvent(category, action, [name], [value])` included. With a onclick event and `_paq.push(['trackEvent', 'Event Category', 'Event Action', 'Event Name'])` you can use it.

See this solution here with code snippets and screenshots: http://pen-ultima.blogspot.com/2018/01/matomo-internal-link-track.html

Comment: When you have enough rep you should add this answer as comment to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31969118/8928024) answer. Welcome to SO. Thanks for posting an answer. Please finish the tour and enjoy SO ;-)